# Output missing a name using BETWEEN clause SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, logic

```
SQL> SELECT name

 FROM donor

 WHERE name BETWEEN J & R;

NAME

-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -

Jennifer Ames

Nancy Taylor
```

A name that should be coming up is Robert Brooks. But Ro is bigger than R so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there:

```
SELECT name
FROM donor
WHERE SUBSTR(NAME,1,1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R';
```

The `SUBSTR` function will only compare the first letters of the names.

Here's an Example:

```
CREATE TABLE DONOR(
  NAME VARCHAR2(128)
);

INSERT INTO DONOR VALUES ('Jennifer Ames');
INSERT INTO DONOR VALUES ('Nancy Taylor');
INSERT INTO DONOR VALUES ('Robert Brooks');

SELECT name
FROM donor
WHERE SUBSTR(NAME,1,1) BETWEEN 'J' AND 'R';
```

Result:

```
NAME           
Jennifer Ames  
Nancy Taylor   
Robert Brooks
```

Comment: Thank you so much alexgibbs

Answer (score 1):

you can use the next letter up in the alphabet?

```
... between 'J' and 'S'
```

Comment: No I have to use J and R here.

Comment: @JBen - why do you **have to** use J and R? What Roger suggests makes perfect sense. The only problem is if you have someone with the name exactly `S` since it will pick up that one, but otherwise the suggestion does **exactly** what you need. If you need to avoid picking up `S` then you can say `where name >= 'J' and name < 'S'`. Compared to the "correct" answer, this approach will work much faster if you have an index on `name`, since using `substr` means the query engine **cannot** use the index.

Comment: @mathguy The instructions on the website stated to not use any other letters.

Comment: @JBen - On what website? You are adding information there was no mention of in your post. Perhaps you don't see what the problem is with that.

Comment: @mathguy - this is the problem when someone wants a 'contrived' homework question resolving. The questions often have nonsensical conditions attached.